# Run Chaos Monkey locally on mac

Tags: testing, spinnaker

I was trying to setup chaos monkey locally on my mac. Couldn't find much documentations regarding this. The official [docs](https://netflix.github.io/chaosmonkey/Running-locally/) are incomplete/ or in progress. I'm new to chaos engineering and have never worked with the simian army tools.

I was able to find a lot of guides to install chaos-monkey on distribution platforms. But couldn't find any useful documentation for doing the same on a local system to test.

I'm aware that I'll need spinnaker and mysql set up for it to run.

I was thinking of installing spinnaker on a local kubernetes cluster and then try configuring that to set up chaos-monkey. I found this [guide](https://costimuraru.wordpress.com/2018/07/06/deploying-spinnaker-on-minikube-kubernetes-using-hal/) to do the same. But ended up overloading my mac (has 8GB ram) and it shut down.

Also tried setting up spinnaker on docker using [this](https://dzone.com/articles/deploying-spinnaker-on-docker-desktop) guide, but ran into some version issues.

Is there any other memory efficient way to install chaos_monkey locally and use it to attack kubernetes nodes or even VMs? I'm aware of kube-monkey, but that's not what I'm trying to test here.

Any suggestions on how to set this up locally are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem around Chaos Monkey a couple of years ago. The setup is complex enough that finding foolproof steps is a little challenging. Here's a comprehensive guide that is useful: https://www.gremlin.com/chaos-monkey/chaos-monkey-tutorial/

As an alternative, Gremlin's Free Product isn't open source, but gives you Chaos Monkey / shutdown functionality with a very simple install process. gremlin.com/gremlin-free-software.